# Having trouble deploying the front end of my mern app

Tags: reactjs, frontend, vercel

I'm currently trying to deploy my first MERN app and I was able to get my server going but my react front end keeps giving me errors such as:

> "Could not resolve "./components/Header.jsx" from "src/App.jsx" and Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Here is my app.jsx file:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./routes/Home/home.jsx";
import About from "./routes/About/about.jsx";
import Comics from "./routes/Comics/comics.jsx"
import SingleComic from "./routes/Comics/singleComic.jsx";
import Header from "./components/Header.jsx";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.jsx";
import CreateComic from "./routes/Comics/createComic.jsx";
import EditComic from "./routes/Comics/editComic.jsx";



function App() {
  return (
   
    <>
    
      <Router>
        <Header/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/" element = { <Home/> } />
          <Route path = "/about" element = { <About/> } />
          <Route path = "/comics" element = { <Comics/> } />
          <Route path = "/comics/:slug" element = { <SingleComic/> } />
          <Route path = "/createcomic" element = { <CreateComic/> } />
          <Route path = "/editcomic/:slug" element = { <EditComic/> } />
         
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: without any code or context it's impossible for us to guess what is going wrong with your project...

Comment: Please read guidelines for posting on stack overflow. There is no context or code to what you're doing so its incredibly hard to try and help you with the information you provided. 

A guess at whats happening here is that you're trying to import files that either don't exist or are in a different location from where you're trying to import them.

Comment: sorry about that, just added my app.jsx file

Answer (score 0):

So, what is happening is that while trying to build your application, the `Header.jsx` file is not found this triggers the error during the building phase.

Some the possible solutions are the following:

- Check file path for `Header.jsx`, make sure is correctly **exported** and **imported**.
- Check for **case sensitivity**: make sure the file name is starting with a capital letter (same as the import name)
- Maybe a typo in the actual file name

Could you also provide  the `Header.jsx` code?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really am appreciative, I’m about to check again and see

Comment: did the suggestion helped you?